# What Environmental Variables PATH I need to add for Qt5 to recognize include <QtGui/QApplication>

Tags: qt, environment-variables, qt5

What Environmental Variables PATH I need to add for Qt5 to recognize include  ?

- I already added “C:\qt5\2012.11\qtbase\bin and C:\qt5\2012.11\qtbase\lib".

I used VS2012 command prompt to build [Qt5Sdk](http://qt.gitorious.org/qtsdk) and it's work, but it's not recognize

> include QtGui/QApplication,
>
> include QFileDialog

and more...it's does recognize

> include QGui

.

maybe VS2012 build didn't goes well?

- BTW in Windows7 where's are the INCLUDE, LIB and LIBPATH, becaise I can see I can set them from Qt, but when entered windows 7 environment variables there is only PATH?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this supposed to be C++? Then a) add the Qt include dirs to your project (assuming ....`qtbase/include/`,`qtbase/include/QtCore`, `qtbase/include/QtGui` etc) and b) fix your include statements (e.g. `#include <QFileDialog>` and c) there is not `QGui` header

Comment: Thanks! I also saw there is a script tool to fix the includes.
and yes it is c++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Qt5, QApplication class was moved from QtGui modul to QtWidgets.

So, instead of

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
```

put

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
```

and instead of

```
QT += core gui
```

you should have

```
QT += core gui widgets
```

Comment: Note that this will make the source incompatible with Qt4. The standard way is to `#include <QApplication>` without a module path and only add `QT += widgets` when on Qt5.

Answer (score 4):

In Qt5, you need to specify the modules you're using in your Qt project file. In this case:

```
QT += widgets
```

This should take care of configuring the include directories correctly.